# How do I get the value in the CJuiAutoComplete textfield in yii?

Tags: autocomplete, yii

I'm using this code. How do I put the value inside into a variable, say $temp?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'name'=>'patientSearch',
    'source'=>$arr,
    // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'minLength'=>'2',
),
'htmlOptions'=>array(
    'style'=>'height:20px;'
),
));

$temp = <value of autocomplete form>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ events sections. Use `select` or `change` events

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
  'name'=>'patientSearch',
  'source'=>$arr,
  // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
  'options'=>array(
        'minLength'=>'2',
        'select' => 'js:function(event, ui) {
$temp = event.currentTarget.value;
}',
        'change' => 'js:function(event, ui) {
$temp = event.currentTarget.value;
}',
  ),
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
    'style'=>'height:20px;'
  ),
));

var $temp = ''; // init global variable
```

Comment: I think `'select' => 'js:function(event, ui) {
$temp = event.currentTarget.value;
}',` will give you the result.